# for primitive pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$, why c must be the form $4k+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I try to use Fermat's two square theorem, but i find c can be composite numbers. I know sum of squares are 0, 1, 2 (mod 4) and 2 is not a square (mod 4). How can i show c cant be 0 (mod 4)

Answer (score 3):

If c is even then 4 divides c². Thus we have a,b cannot both be odd else 4 does not divide a²+b² only 2 does. So both a,b are even and the triple is no longer primitive.